# Precise Definition of a Limit

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question regarding a proof in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, page 84. Let X and Y be metric spaces. Suppose $E \subset X$, f maps E into Y, and p is a limit point of E. Then $\lim_{x\to p} f(x)$ = q iff $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(p_n)$ = q for every sequence ${p_n}$ such that $p_n \neq p$, and $\lim_{n\to \infty} p_n$ = p.

My question is, why must it be that $p_n \neq p$? It seems reasonable that you could have a sequence converging to p but contains p in the sequence (e.g. all the even terms = p, and all the odd terms are approaching p as $n \to \infty$). So if $p_n = p$ for some n in the sequence does this definition somehow break down?

Comment: It won't break down, because in the end you would still have $\lim_{n \to \infty }p_n = p$

Answer (score 1):

I think that the point is it shouldn't matter matter what the value of $f$ is at $p$. In particular, this means that $f$ doesn't even have to be defined at $p$. All we care about is the value $f$ approaches as it gets closer to $p$.

If it is the case that $f(p)$ is defined and $f(p) = q$, then we would have continuity.

Comment: Right, I think that's what it's trying to say but I wanted to double check because you can say the same thing and omit the $p_n \neq p$, right?

Answer (score 1):

By the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)=L$, the value of the limit $L$ does not depend on $f(p)$. You can change $f(p)$ to anything you like, and that won't affect $L$.

However, if you have a sequence $\{ x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converging to $p$ with infinitely many terms equal to $p$, then changing the value of $f(p)$ can cause $\lim_{n}f(x_{n})$ to no longer exist. So you know the traditional limit definition and your proposed one cannot be the same.

Answer (score 0):

As for the question if the definition breaks down: No, it will not, because all the requirement $p_n\neq p$ means is that you have less sequences to check than if there was no such requirement.